# Having trouble converting php associative array to string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I want to convert a php array to a json string, and pass that string through an asynchronous web request. When the webrequest is made... that string I passed has the value "[Object object]" which I don't want.

Slightly simplified:

```
$positionCounterArray = array("QB"=>1, "RB"=>1);
$positionCounterArrayString = json_encode($positionCounterArray);
```

later in the javascript...

```
<script>

var numberOfPlayers = <?php echo $positionCounterArrayString; ?>;
alert(numberOfPlayers);
var query = "./queries/queryForAvailablePlayers.php?playerId="+playerId+"&userId="+id+"&numberOfPlayers="+numberOfPlayers;

</script>
```

Corresponding to the section of code directly above, when I right click and view source code I see:

```
var numberOfPlayers = {"QB":0,"RB":0};
alert(numberOfPlayers);
```

I guess this makes sense... alert(numberOfPlayers) isn't bound until run time so we won't see the value: {"QB":0,"RB":0} yet

But when I actually RUN it, my pop up alert is [Object object] instead of the string json string I was hoping for: {"QB":0,"RB":0}

The whole problem is that when I send my query, it sends ./queries/queryForAvailablePlayers.php?playerId=179&userId=2&numberOfPlayers=[Object object]. This query is caught like this and I cannot use the json_decode($_GET['numberOfPlayers'], true) to get it back into the associative array to extract the values and eventually use to query against my DB.

Any help with this matter is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be string instead of js object, you need to add quotes in the js:

Instead of:

```
var numberOfPlayers = <?php echo $positionCounterArrayString; ?>;
```

do this:

```
var numberOfPlayers = '<?php echo $positionCounterArrayString; ?>';  //See the quotes
```

**EDIT (extra)**

Also, it's always recommended to escape your url params, so

```
var query = ... +id+"&numberOfPlayers="+numberOfPlayers;
```

should better be:

```
var query = ... +id+"&numberOfPlayers="+encodeURIComponent(numberOfPlayers);
```

Cheers

Comment: I guess I am getting confused. I thought the json_encode function produced a string: "Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value." Source: http://www.php.net/json_encode. I will try what you are saying in just a moment. But my hope is that i could pass as a string and use json_decode to turn that string in jason format back into an associative array so I can pluck out values in there, say the RB

Comment: @don Yes, it produces a string. But if you put that string into source code, it's being interpreted as code, and you should be able to see that in the produced code it's not a string at all.

Comment: @donsiuch Exactly what deceze said, I was about to say the same

Comment: @donsiuch json_encode produces a PHP string, but in js it's just js code (not js string)

Comment: OK thanks for the help guys. This works how I want it to now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're outputting to Javascript is a Javascript object literal (which is what JSON is essentially), so the Javascript variable will hold an object, not a string. As such the alert is perfectly correct, the variable holds an object. Try `console.log` instead of `alert` to get a more complete debug value in your browser's console.

I find this to be preferable as opposed to transporting a string, since you can do something directly with a native Javascript object in your Javascript. You just have to take care to properly format the object for use in a URL instead of just concatenating it, the same you'd have to treat any object variable you have in Javascript.